# Does chrome-headless support reuse browser session using selenium webdriver ?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless-browser

I know of chrome having support for reusing browser session using selenium webdriver.

Is it available for `Headless Chrome` as well ? If so, is there some difference with respect to chrome

Comment: Would be interested to know as it could streamline processes which are otherwise tedious to repeat each time (eg headless doesn't work for our SSO solutions, so we need to repeat login steps each time, whereas re-using session would side-step this competently)

Comment: @Neil, yes you can use session reuse with headless version just like with normal chrome.